# Can someone modify another guy's answer?

Tags: discussion

Suppose it's not community wiki?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As stated by the [FAQ](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/faq): Once you have 2000 rep, you can edit other people's posts.

*EDIT: or if you are a moderator.*

Comment: I'm talking about answer,not question.

Comment: an answer is also a post

Comment: It applies to questions and answers.

Comment: Of course, there's still an audit trail anyway :)

Comment: What moderator does not have 2000 rep?

Comment: @Isaac moderators of small sites

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/2/Geoff-Dalgas doesn't have very much rep, but is still a moderator. ( He is one of the guys that works on the code base. )

Answer (score 3):

**Yes.**

*(I am assuming this is a 'moral' question and not a 'technical' question.)*

And I've done it before.

*Example:* Correcting someone's code so that it at least compiles, etc.  Not in the heat of the responses, but I came along weeks later and the answer answered my own question, co I copied the code.  It did not work, lacked private modifiers, etc.  So I fixed it.

This is all in the spirit of SO.

There is a line where one could go to far, like trivial edits, which is a full on topic here on MSO.